# Linear homogeneous system having non-trivial solution is equivalent with a set of vectors being linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

How can i prove that the following conditions are equivalent:

If $m<n$, then a homogeneous system of $m$ equations in $n$ variables with coefficients in a field $F$ has a nontrivial solution.

If a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is generated by $m$ elements, and $v_1, ...,v_n$ are elements of $V$ with $m<n$, then $v_1, ..., v_n$ is linearly dependent.

I can prove this with some examples  and i tried to use if $v_1, ...,v_n$ are in $V$ and exist a $k$ in ${i,...,n}$ such that $v_k = 0$ then $v_1, ..., v_n$ is linearly dependent
but  i stuck here, how can i prove  this both statements are equivalents in general.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$\Rightarrow$": Let $V$ be the span of $m$ vectors, so $\dim V\le m$. Take a family of $n$ vectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$ for $n>m$. To check if these are linearly dependent, we need to look at the equation
$$
\lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n v_n = 0.
$$
Splitting this into the $\dim V$ coordinates, we get a system of $\dim V$ equations and $n$ variables. By assumption this system has a nontrivial solution, thus the family $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is linearly dependent.

"$\Leftarrow$": Take a homogeneous system of $m$ equations in $n$ variables, where $m<n$. We can express this system as an equation in $F^m$ that looks like
$$
\lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n v_n = 0
$$
for $v_i\in F^m$. Since the $n$ vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are elements of an $m$-dimensional vector space and $m<n$, by assumption they are linearly dependent. Thus the equation has a nontrivial solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, the two statements are *always* true, so they are trivially equivalent (which by definition means that one statement is true if and only if the other is true).

But here there is a more direct link. You can assume without loss of generality that $\dim V=m$ (your $m$ vectors generating $V$ are a basis), because if they do not, you throw away some redundant vectors, which will only decrease $m$, and $m<n$ will remain true.

Now write the equation for unknown (scalar) coefficients $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to give a relation $x_1v_1+\cdots+x_nv_n=0$, then this means that all $m$ coordinates of the left hand side must be $0$. Writing that down gives a homogeneous system of $m$ equations in $n$ variables. Linear dependence of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ pricisely means the system has a non-trivial solution.